# Is there any open source project similar to the django admin, but in .NET?

Tags: .net, django-admin

I would like to know if there exists some reusable/pluggable modules which implement CRUD operations on users, groups, roles and permissions available to be integrated in .NET web applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, ASP.NET includes providers for membership, roles, and profiles. The CRUD operations are embedded within the classes that implement them. You can either create the memberships and roles using Visual Studio (usually these go in a private database in the App_Data folder), or you can run aspnet_regsql (command line utility) to set up the membership and roles tables in an existing SQL Server database. There is also a provider that works with Active Directory instead of SQL Server.

I've used the SQL Server provider in a couple of applications and it works very well. It integrates very smoothly with ASP.NET authentication and authorization. I'm not sure why you would want to go with something else; if there's a reason that the ASP.NET providers don't meet your needs, then please expand on that.

Answer (score 1):

Cylon cat said it; it's built-in.

There's an administrative front end called the [Web Site Administration Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0.aspx) which you can run to configure security very easily.

Answer (score 0):

The most similar thing I've found, are [these series of tutorials](http://www.asp.net/learn/security/) in ASP.NET